# Teamcity trigger only when specified VCS master branch

Tags: git, teamcity

`A project` has 7 VCS sources, and I want to make a trigger only by *one* VCS when `<default>` branch has a new commit.

For that, I registered rule as below;

- Per-checkin Triggering: unchecked.
- **Trigger Rules** `+:root=ProjectA_Android:**`
- **Branch Filter**: `+:<default>`

But it does not work as I expected. It just has `Pending` status.
What am I missing?

Note that `ProjectA_Android` is name of VCS root ID, `default` is `ref/heads/master`, and Teamcity is `2017.2.3` version.